# Data truncation: in mysql

Tags: jstl

I have a input field

```
    <body>
    <center>
    <div style="margin-top : 1px; border:1px solid #e4e4e4; width : 500px; background: #efefef; box-shadow : 0px 0px 20px 10px #e5e5e5 inset;">
        <p style="font-size: 18pt; font-family: verdana; text-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #000; color:#fff;">Student Exam Data</p>
        <form onsubmit="return message()">
            <p class="heading">Student Details</p>
            <p class="data">
                <label>Roll Number</label><input type="text" name="rollno" id="rollno" maxlength="4"/>
            </p>
            <p class="heading">Marks Obtained For Languages</p>
            <p class="data">
                <label>English</label><input type="text" name="english" id="english" onchange="calculate()" maxlength="3"/>
            </p>
            <p class="data">
                <label>Konkani</label><input type="text" name="konkani" id="konkani" onchange="calculate() maxlength="3""/>
            </p>

            <p class="heading">Marks Obtained For Natural Science</p>
            <p class="data">
                <label>Maths</label><input type="text" name="maths" id="maths" onchange="calculate() maxlength="3""/>
            </p>
            <p class="data">
                <label>Physics</label><input type="text" name="physics" id="physics" onchange="calculate() maxlength="3""/>
            </p>
            <p class="data">
                <label>Chemistry</label><input type="text" name="chemistry" id="chemistry" onchange="calculate() maxlength="3""/>
            </p>

            <p class="heading">Marks Obtained For Social Science</p>
            <p class="data">
                <label>Geography</label><input type="text" name="geography" id="geography" onchange="calculate() maxlength="3""/>
            </p>

            <p class="heading">Total Marks Obtained</p>
            <p class="data">
                <label>Total Marks</label><input type="text" name="total" id="total" readonly="readonly"/>
            </p>

            <p class="heading">Percentage</p>
            <p class="data">
                <label>Percentage</label><input type="text" name="percentage" id="percentage" readonly="readonly"/>
            </p>

            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            </p>

            <input type="hidden" name="mode" value="set">

        </form>
    </div>
    </center>



    <c:if test="${param.mode == 'set'}">

    roll number<c:out value="${param.rollno}"></c:out>
        <c:catch var="exception">
            <sql:setDataSource var="examDatabase" password="" user="root" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/examination"/>
            <sql:update var="result" sql="insert into student_examdata values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)" dataSource="${examDatabase}">

                <sql:param value="${param.rollno}.trim()"></sql:param>
                <sql:param value="${param.english}.trim()"></sql:param>
                <sql:param value="${param.maths}.trim()"></sql:param>
                <sql:param value="${param.physics}.trim()"></sql:param>
                <sql:param value="${param.chemistry}.trim()"></sql:param>
                <sql:param value="${param.konkani}.trim()"></sql:param>
                <sql:param value="${param.geography}.trim()"></sql:param>
                <sql:param value="${param.total}.trim()"></sql:param>
                <sql:param value="${param.percentage}.trim()"></sql:param>
            </sql:update>
        </c:catch>



        <c:if test="${exception != null }">
            <p class="error">
            <strong style="background : #fff; color:#000; width : 300px;">Exception</strong><br><br>
            <c:out value="${exception.message}"></c:out>
        </p>
        </c:if>

    </c:if>



</body>
```

the data type of the field roll_no is varchar(4).

Error is:
insert into student_examdata values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?): Data truncation: Data too long for column 'roll_no' at row 1

please help.

Comment: And what is the data type and definition of `param.rollno`? If the error happens at run-time it is likely that `param.rollno` contains the string longer than 4 chars.

Comment: i have added the full code....

Comment: have you tried debugging it to check that the value being inserted is not larger than 4 characters?

Comment: Yes i debuged the code.... it tried entering 12 as rollno its still giving me the error.

Comment: Okai... i figured it out... it ws the .trim() that was getting counted....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something is seriously wrong here!

```
<sql:param value="${param.rollno}.trim()"></sql:param>
```

if you are trying to trim the rollno, please use this

```
<sql:param value="${param.rollno.trim()}"></sql:param>
```

i hope that will answer your problem!